# Trying to bind dynamic title(interpolation) in kendo tabstrip in angular2

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I am trying to bind interpolated title into kendo tabstrip for angular2, but my code is not working.

*code without interpolation, tist is working fine but interpolation is not working !

```
   <kendo-tabstrip>
     <kendo-tabstrip-tab **[title]="'Paris'" ** [selected]="true">
       <ng-template kendoTabContent>
       </ng-template>
     </kendo-tabstrip-tab>
  <kendo-tabstrip-tab **[title]="'New York City'" **>
    <ng-template kendoTabContent>
    </ng-template>
  </kendo-tabstrip-tab>
  <kendo-tabstrip-tab [title]="'Tallinn'">
    <ng-template kendoTabContent>
    </ng-template>
  </kendo-tabstrip-tab>
  <kendo-tabstrip-tab [title]="'Sydney'" [disabled]="true"></kendo-tabstrip-tab>
</kendo-tabstrip>
```

hardcode data:

```
public cities=[
    {"city":"Paris"},
    {"city":"London"}
    ]
```

Tryied code:

```
  <kendo-tabstrip>
            <kendo-tabstrip-tab [title]="item.city" [selected]="true" *ngFor="let item of cities">
              <ng-template kendoTabContent>

              </ng-template>
            </kendo-tabstrip-tab>
    <kendo-tabstrip>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try that: *ngFor="let item of cities">

Comment: actually it is cities, i forgot to change the name

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this code and it's work for me:

```
<kendo-tabstrip (tabSelect)="onTabSelected($event)">
    <kendo-tabstrip-tab *ngFor="let tab of tabs;" [title]="'title ' + tab.title)" [selected]="tab.isSelected">
        <ng-template kendoTabContent>
            // your  tab content
        </ng-template>
    </kendo-tabstrip-tab>
</kendo-tabstrip>`
```